# How to autocall a function with a Listbox based on data in a separate Entry Widget without a button

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to have my Listbox automatically run a query and populate immediately when corresponding Entry box has a value.  This would be done without the use of a UPDATE or SELECT button(command=). If all fails I will have to resort to a button function call...  I was hoping this could be accomplished without the use of a button. Essentially the autoquery would get (l) from 'team_input' and update levlistbox with the database result.

```
def autoquery(l):
   levListbox.delete(0, "end")
   l = team_input.get()
   cursor = dbi.cursor()
   cursor.execute("""SELECT level FROM teamstatus WHERE game='%s'"""%(l,))
   rows = cursor.fetchall()
   for results in rows:
      levListbox.insert("end", results)
   root.after(5000, autoquery)

root = Tk() 

teamLabel=Label(topListFrame, text="Team", font="Verdana 8 bold")
teamLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)
team_input = StringVar()
team_input = Entry(topListFrame, textvariable=team_input, width=10)
team_input.grid(row=1,column=0)

levLabel=Label(topListFrame, text="Level", font="Verdana 8 bold")
levLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)
levListbox=Listbox(topListFrame, height=1,width=8)

#TRIED TO USE lambda  WITH autoquery(team_input))

levListbox.grid(row=1, column=1)

autoquery()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can callback a method when the string in an entry is changed by making use of [special tkinter variables or variable classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) such as `StringVar` and the method `trace_add`. Now you already seem to want to use `StringVar` but:

```
team_input = StringVar()
team_input = Entry(topListFrame, textvariable=team_input, width=10)
```

lines make `team_input` first be the variable class required to do that but you then overwrite that variable with Entry which makes not much sense. Try replacing to:

```
team_input_var = StringVar()
team_input = Entry(topListFrame, textvariable=team_input_var, width=10)
```

and then add before `mainloop`:

```
team_input_var.trace_add('write', autoquery)
```

If you want to call `autoquery` whenever what's written in entry is changed.

Also note that `def autoquery(l)` looks redundant, but since `trace_add` sends 3 somewhat not related arguments, replace it with `def autoquery(*args)`.

Comment: First of all I keep forgetting to make sure my Strvar name is not the same as my Entry name ...aaaah.  I will try the trace_add - THANKS

Comment: with the above changes including (*args) the SQL string (l) won't work. cursor.execute("""SELECT level FROM teamstatus WHERE game='%s'"""%(l,)). I get NameError: name 'l' is not defined

Comment: I uncommented my l=team_input.get() and its working fine.  Thanks a mill...

Comment: Sorry I was getting errors so I was commenting to troubleshoot but forgot to remove.  Trust me all my fault - just an update.  Thanks again